# Not able to see any content after upgrade to 2010

Tags: upgrade

I have upgrade my content database in sharepoint 2010. The site collections are there but when I open the new sharepoint site the content from the 2007 content database is not being display.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue? 
Should I create a new web application and attach a new copy of the content database?
Any help will be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: are you seeing the empty default site instead? Go to Central Admin > Application Management > Manage Content Databases. Do you see your database there and the site count? Is there another content DB here as well?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you detach the Content Database that was created by default when you created your web application as there cannot be two root site collections associated with a web application.  You might need to restart IIS for it to pick up that the other site collection / Content Database has been removed)

Comment: Yes, the database is there and the site count is 1190. No other database is attach. I detach the default DB when I created the web application. I already restart IIS and still my old content is not being display on the new web application. Any ideas on what else I should check or do before I start all over again. Thanks for replying.

Comment: There is a root site collection in your attached database, correct?

Comment: Do I need to create a site collection for the web application?

Comment: I have "/" , " /mysite" and "/personal/username" . I believe "/" is my root site collection. I checked the documentation and I did not read about creating a new site collection. But I  might be wrong.